# Protecting PDF's

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

I have created a word document. I now want to convert it into a PDF. I want the following features in the pdf

Text in pdf can be copied
Text in pdf can be printed

However text cannot be edited in any case. I am adding a footer information to each page and I want that users should never be able to edit the footer.

Is there a way I can do this. Please share all options

Comment: are you using microsoft office and if yes then which version ?

Answer (score 2):

If the PDF can be printed then it cannot be protected.

The copier would only need to print it to a virtual pdf printer, and would that way get an unlocked version.

Conclusion: Don't bother.

Comment: And if it _is_ print protected, you could just open it in a reader that does not care about protection (i.e. evince on linux) and do whatever you want with it. Acrobat protection is only as good as the application used to read the document.

Answer (score 1):

Not using MS Word 2007 'Save As > PDF' option, but you can add this kind of secureity using other PDF creators.

For example, if you have [Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobatpro/tryout.html) installed you can use the 'Save As > Adobe PDF' option in MS Word, click the 'Options...' button in the 'Save Adobe PDF File As' dialog and tick the'Apply Security' box. Then apply the settings as below:

[image: Acrobat PDF Maker security dialog]

This will give you the copying etc. restrictions but still allow printing:

[image: PDF document security summary]

Answer (score 0):

regardless of what the other answers say, any built in protection provided by PDF making software can be removed easily. Just Google PDF security removal and you will see. There is no such thing as absolute security.